# How to rig disconnected meshes in Blender

Tags: mesh, rigging

[image]

I have created character mesh as well as character rigg (skeleton).

When I try to parent this rigged skeleton to the mesh, Blender outputs error. I've read somewhere that the cause of this is that I try to rigg disconnected meshes. However, this character model is one object. When I move it all parts are moving along.

How shall I parent it correctly?

Comment: Can you upload the blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It should be possible imho, there must be some rigging or weights issue... use the suggested link, then add the provided link to your question..

Comment: I can not upload the file. It's copyrighted. The error I got in blender is: 'Bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones'.

Comment: Also: I got this error when I choose: set parent to -> armaturę deform -> with automatic weights.